# My Minecraft's Player rig doesn't have shadows, how to fix?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, light, shadows

So, I have a Minecraft's player rig, I've put a light spot and made the render, but I can't see the shadow of the rig, how can I fix it?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Activate shadows in the lamp options

Comment: Mae sure that the plane is set to receive shadows.

Comment: because monsters may come if too much shadow in Minecraft ?

Comment: Im afraid she doesnt have a soul and thus, is unable to cast shadows. Sry

Answer (score 1):

Select your light object, head over to the light options tab on the right hand side, and turn on shadows.

Answer (score 0):

Go under World and check Ambient Occlusion, If you want softer shadows.